# How do doubles squash rules vary from singles rules?

Tags: rules, officiating, squash

When playing doubles squash, what are the rules that vary from the singles rules?

For Example:

- Do players in the team have to hit the ball alternately, or can either player hit the ball?
- Does a team have to elect a server or can either player serve or does it alternate wthin the team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [US Doubles Squash rules](http://www.ussquash.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Squash-Doubles-Playing-Rules.pdf): (emphasis added)

> The two partners of a side shall serve in succession, the first
>   retaining his serve until his side has lost  a point. **On the loss of a
>   subsequent point the side shall be declared *out* and the serve
>   revert to the  opponents. On the first serve of every game, however,
>   the *in* side shall be declared *out* after it has lost one  point
>   only**. The order of serving within a side shall not be changed during
>   the progress of a game. At the end of  a game the side which has won
>   the game shall have the choice of serving or receiving to commence the
>   next  game.

and

> (b) At the beginning of each game each side shall designate one of its
>   players to receive service in the right hand service court and the
>   other to receive service in the left hand service court and throughout
>   the course of  such game the service must be received by the players
>   so designated.

So to answer this question:

> Do players in the team have to hit the ball alternately, or can either player hit the ball?

They have to hit it alternately for serving and while receiving, the person who is assigned the right hand service court should return those hits and the other person show return hits on left hand service court. This shouldn't be changed through out the game.

> Does a team have to elect a server or can either player serve or does it alternate within the team?

It is alternate within a team.

For more details on other aspects of game, you can check the above link which I mentioned.